# Custom Query with Cdbcriteria

Tags: yii

How can I execute this query with CDbCriteria and CActiveDataProvider?

```
'SELECT * FROM tbl_post where title LIKE %'.$title.'% ORDER BY title LIKE '.$title.' DESC , title LIKE '.$title.'% DESC'
```

**update:**
finaly I wrote this:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
                    $criteria->addCondition('title LIKE :title');                        
                    $criteria->params = array(':title'=>'%'.$title.'%',':t1'=>$title,':t2'=>$title.'%');;
                    $criteria->order='title LIKE :t1 DESC , title LIKE :t2 DESC';
```

but I got error:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tbl_post` `t` WHERE title LIKE :title
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using compare clause, not sure is it you want with the 'order by x like' :

```
<?php
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->compare('title', $title, true);
$criteria->order = 'title DESC';
$dp = new CActiveDataprovider('posts', array(
  'criteria' => $criteria
));
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved like this:

```
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('tbl_post', array(
    'criteria'=>array(
    'condition'=>'title LIKE % '.$title.' %',
    'order'=>'title DESC',
    ),
   ));

    $dataProvider->getData();
```

also refer : [Help](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider)

Thanks.